I have a issue with "flutter build apk",also there's no flutter folder in the project/build/app/outputs
I'm triying to build my flutter apk using flutter build apk, But it says
`
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uni_links2:verifyReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:C:\Users\DELL\bitsnbytes\HomeIQ - App\smarthome\build\uni_links2\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           12.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
`
How do i resolve this ???
i want to download my release-apk.

too old pkg, try to find a update fork  on github repo

Try with Flutter pub cache clean , Flutter pub cache repair , flutter pub get , after that create release apps using flutter build apk --release

compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are set to a version that supports the lStar attribute. You can set them to 33 or higher. Update your build.gradle file
:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 33
    }
}

then clean and build apk:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk --release


Update Gradle and Plugin Versions
Make sure your build.gradle files are using compatible versions. Open your project-level build.gradle file and check the following:
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31' // or latest stable version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4' // or latest stable version
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

